# Detecting User or GDI Objects leak in own managed code

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, memory-leaks

My **Windows Forms** program had that "Error creating window handle"-Exception recently, which is a symptom of a User Objects leak.
I had some rough idea what happened and could confirm it by watching the "User objects" and "GDI objects" columns in task manager slowly climbing up when I interacted with the program in a certain way. So, I know what exactly do I need to do to observe the leak (basically, add a thing via GUI and then remove it).

Now comes the tricky part: finding what exact control is the source of the leak.

Since it is my program and I have full access to the source-code, there should be no need for the advanced methods, I think. After some googling, I came with following idea.

1. Use `SetWindowsHookEx` to set a hook for `CALLWNDPROC`
2. In the hook-function, look for `WM_CREATE` and `WM_DESTROY`
3. on `WM_CREATE`, store the handle, `CREATESTRUCT.lpszName` and classname, as well as the stacktrace
4. on `WM_DESTROY`, delete previously stored data for the handle

(the code I used is at the bottom of this post).

By looking at the stored data, with some luck I actually did find one leak (a tooltip wasn't properly disposed.)

But there is something else leaking: both "User objects" and "GDI objects" columns in task manager are increasing by 1 when I perform my interactions (add a thing - delete a thing), and now I have no idea.

The [GDIView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) shows increment in "All GDI" but none of the other columns.

There is the marvelous [EasyHook](http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/createlocalhook.html), but I don't know what function to hook (first idea would be `CreateWindowEx`/`DestroyWindow`, but they give same result)

I know there are similar questions, but I couldn't find a method to actually get that exact control (and code line where the handler is created) like I was able to do with my code below (I hope to create some sort of developer tool, probably in form of a huge code snippet, I could use in other projects to detect such leaks).

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

'Usage:
' set breakpoint in LeakSearch.Stop()
' Call LeakSearch.Start()
' -- interact with the program somehow
' Call LeakSearch.Stop()
' inspect the List `l`
Public Class LeakSearch
    Private Shared _open_handles As Dictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
    Public Shared Sub Start()
        _open_handles = New Dictionary(Of IntPtr, String)

        ToggleHook()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub [Stop]()
        ToggleHook()

        Dim l = (From hs In _open_handles Group By stack = hs.Value Into cnt = Count() Order By cnt Descending).ToList

        Dim x = 1 'set breakpoint here
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub NewHandle(handle As IntPtr, pCreateStruct As IntPtr)
        Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"NewHandle:   {handle.ToString("x8")} ")

        Dim MyCREATESTRUCT As CREATESTRUCT = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCreateStruct, GetType(CREATESTRUCT)), CREATESTRUCT)
        Dim name As String = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(MyCREATESTRUCT.lpszName)
        Dim classname As String = GetClassName(handle)
        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CREATESTRUCT: {name} {classname}")

        Dim st = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(True)

        If Not _open_handles.ContainsKey(handle) Then
            _open_handles.Add(handle, $"name={name}{vbNewLine}classname={classname}{vbNewLine}{st.ToString}")
        Else
            Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Double!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub RemoveHandle(handle As IntPtr)
        Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"RemoveHandle:   {handle.ToString("x8")} ")

        If _open_handles.ContainsKey(handle) Then
            _open_handles.Remove(handle)
        Else
            Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" -- not found?!!")
        End If

        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("")
    End Sub

    Private Shared hHookCallWND As Integer = 0
    Private Shared Sub ToggleHook()
        If hHookCallWND = 0 Then
            CallWndHookProcedure = New HookProc(AddressOf CallWndHookProc)
            hHookCallWND = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndHookProcedure, CType(0, IntPtr), GetCurrentThreadId())

            If hHookCallWND = 0 Then
                Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetWindowsHookEx Failed")
                Return
            End If

            Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hooked - CallWND")
        Else
            Dim ret As Boolean = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHookCallWND)

            If ret = False Then
                Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UnhookWindowsHookEx Failed")
                Return
            End If

            hHookCallWND = 0
            Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unhooked - CallWND")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Function HookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Enum HookType As Integer
        WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0
        WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1
        WH_KEYBOARD = 2
        WH_GETMESSAGE = 3
        WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4
        WH_CBT = 5
        WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6
        WH_MOUSE = 7
        WH_HARDWARE = 8
        WH_DEBUG = 9
        WH_SHELL = 10
        WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11
        WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
        WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    End Enum

    Private Const WM_CREATE As Integer = 1
    Private Const WM_DESTROY As Integer = 1

    Public Shared Function CallWndHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        Dim MyCallWndHookStruct As CWPSTRUCT = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, GetType(CWPSTRUCT)), CWPSTRUCT)

        If nCode < 0 Then
            Return CallNextHookEx(hHookCallWND, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        Else
            Select Case MyCallWndHookStruct.message
                Case WM_CREATE
                    NewHandle(MyCallWndHookStruct.hwnd, MyCallWndHookStruct.lParam)
                Case WM_DESTROY
                    RemoveHandle(MyCallWndHookStruct.hwnd)
                Case Else
                    '
            End Select
            Return CallNextHookEx(hHookCallWND, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        End If
    End Function

#Region " CallWndHook "
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure CWPSTRUCT
        Public lParam As IntPtr
        Public wParam As IntPtr
        Public message As Integer
        Public hwnd As IntPtr
    End Structure

    Private Shared CallWndHookProcedure As HookProc

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Structure CREATESTRUCT
        Public lpCreateParams As IntPtr
        Public hInstance As IntPtr
        Public hMenu As IntPtr
        Public hwndParent As IntPtr
        Public cy As Integer
        Public cx As Integer
        Public y As Integer
        Public x As Integer
        Public style As Integer
        Public lpszName As IntPtr
        Public lpszClass As IntPtr
        Public dwExStyle As Integer

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return "X: " & x & ",Y: " & y
        End Function
    End Structure

#End Region

#Region " Win API "

    Public Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr) As String
        Dim length As Integer = 64
        Do While (True)
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder("", length)
            Dim OK As Integer = GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
            If (OK = 0) Then Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
            If (sb.Length <> length - 1) Then Return sb.ToString()
            length *= 2
        Loop
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    '"In .NET Framework 4.0, only CharSet.Ansi seems to produce the result." ???
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As HookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal threadId As UInteger) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    'because "System.AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() (This is deprecated in .NET 2.0)"
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As UInteger
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to start removing code until the leak disappears.

Comment: If the *"All GDI"* values go up, but none of the others, you should probably look into hooking [AddAtom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-addatomw) and [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx) (as well as the respective cleanup functions). [How can I investigate the possibility of a lot of leaked window classes (RegisterClass)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171006-00/?p=97147) may have related information.

Comment: You can also create a minidump of the program using the Debugging Tools and inspect the dump, e.g. looking for the interesting objects on the managed heap etc.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html.  I _think_ it's free.  There are also some other similar tools out there - start sleuthing!

Comment: @IInspectable So, there is no central "NewEntryInGdiSharedHandleTable"-function? Is there maybe a list of all function that can create a GDI object?

Comment: @KBO I can even debug it with WinDbg and inspect the heap, the problem is with finding those interesting objects; I still do hope for something like what I did for the User Handles.

Comment: @PaulSanders The GDIView is free, and I even link it in the question; unfortunately, it doesn't show any "extended information" in my case, and, say, a new DC with handle "0xfd10210e" isn't really helping me. Please tell me how could I use this to get something related to my actual code (in the code sample I show how to get windows' class name, window name and call stack when an user object is created; I think - and hope - there is a way to do the same for GDI object and I'm just lacking the knowledge)